# Variable equal to a jQuery object

Tags: jquery, html, css, arrays

I have 3 spans as follows:

```js
dot1 = $('#loading-dots-1');
dot1.delay(500, function() {
  dot1.show(500);
});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:300i,400,600&display=swap');

.main-text {
  width: calc(100%);
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 6vw;
  color: #000;
  text-align: center;
}

.loading-dots {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <!--Here's my doubt-->
  <div id="preloader-text" class="main-text">
    <p>Loading
      <span id="loading-dots-1" class="loading-dots">.</span>
      <span id="loading-dots-2" class="loading-dots">.</span>
      <span id="loading-dots-3" class="loading-dots">.</span>
    </p>
  </div>

  <!--Don't mind me, I'm just jQuery-->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

See that? jQuery did not `.show(500)` the element because I used `dot1`. Had I directly used the following, it will show the required output (show the dot immediately following "Loading").

```js
$('#loading-dots-1').delay(500, function() {
  dot1.show(500);
});
```

How will I go about using the variable `dot1` to do the same?

Comment: var dot1 = $('#loading-dots-1');

Comment: The second example doesn't work either: https://jsfiddle.net/hLougmbz/ The `opacity` is set to 0; `show()` only affects `display`.

Comment: @HereticMonkey huh! Looks like I've made a grave mistake...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to change `loading-dots` class to use display since `.show()` method changes display property of an element.

Second `.delay()` function does not accept function as a second parameter (it is of type string). You can simply chain jquery effects like this: 
`$('#loading-dots-1').delay(500).show(500);`

A little modified code is below, hope that this answers your question.

```js
const dot1 = $('#loading-dots-1');
dot1.delay(500).show(500);
const dot2 = $('#loading-dots-2');
dot2.delay(1000).show(500);
const dot3 = $('#loading-dots-3');
dot3.delay(1500).show(500);
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:300i,400,600&display=swap');

.main-text {
  width: calc(100%);
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 6vw;
  color: #000;
  text-align: center;
}

.loading-dots {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <!--Here's my doubt-->
  <div id="preloader-text" class="main-text">
    <p>Loading
      <span id="loading-dots-1" class="loading-dots">.</span>
      <span id="loading-dots-2" class="loading-dots">.</span>
      <span id="loading-dots-3" class="loading-dots">.</span>
    </p>
  </div>

  <!--Don't mind me, I'm just jQuery-->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Yeah. I thought jQuery considers objects hidden even while their opacity is set to 0. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A couple things. The `delay()` func changes the display property, not opacity, so you have to give the dots a `display:none` in their default state. Secondly, `delay()` doesn't take a callback func as an argument. Instead, you need to chain `show()` to it.

```js
let dot1 = $('#loading-dots-1');
dot1.delay(500).show(500);
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:300i,400,600&display=swap');

.main-text {
  width: calc(100%);
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 6vw;
  color: #000;
  text-align: center;
}

.loading-dots {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <!--Here's my doubt-->
  <div id="preloader-text" class="main-text">
    <p>Loading
      <span id="loading-dots-1" class="loading-dots">.</span>
      <span id="loading-dots-2" class="loading-dots">.</span>
      <span id="loading-dots-3" class="loading-dots">.</span>
    </p>
  </div>

  <!--Don't mind me, I'm just jQuery-->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use `settimeout` togather with show.
And also your first example should work, it did not work becouse you have `opacity: 0;` it should be `display:none` instead
See below

```js
var dots = $(".loading-dots")
var index = -1;
function loading(){

if (index == dots.length -1)
   {
     index=0;
     dots.hide();
   }else index++;
   $(dots[index]).show(500, function(){
    setTimeout(loading,501)
   });
  

}
loading()
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:300i,400,600&display=swap');

.main-text {
  width: calc(100%);
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 6vw;
  color: #000;
  text-align: center;
}

.loading-dots {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!--Here's my doubt-->
  <div id="preloader-text" class="main-text">
    <p>Loading
      <span id="loading-dots-1" class="loading-dots">.</span>
      <span id="loading-dots-2" class="loading-dots">.</span>
      <span id="loading-dots-3" class="loading-dots">.</span>
    </p>
  </div>

  <!--Don't mind me, I'm just jQuery-->
```

Comment: Nice method for the dots, actually. I was using a switch case as a work around thinking I can't define an array of jQuery objects. Thanks a lot!